# application URL gives 404 error after deployment

Tags: deployment, http-status-code-404, tomcat6, war

I am using tomcat v.6.0 . I have successfully deployed the .war file as a manager. I can see the exploded folder in the webapps directory of tomcat. I can access `http://localhost:8080` . but when i try to access /myapp, i am getting a 404 error. when i checked the console on eclipse (which is where i am handling tomcat and myapp from) , i see the following :

Apr 17, 2013 10:56:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/submitServer/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/submitServer/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 466; columnNumber: 19; Error at (466, 19: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name SourceTextFilter

I checked line 466 in the web.xml file and it is all fine

```
    463 <filter-mapping>
    464      <filter-name>SourceTextFilter</filter-name>
    465      <url-pattern>/view/project.jsp</url-pattern>
    466 </filter-mapping> 
    467 <filter-mapping>
    468 <filter-name>SourceTextFilter</filter-name>
```

I have searched on the internet and stackoverflow for similar questions and their solutions, but none of them seemed to help me.

Comment: Have you defined the Filter class in web.xml ?

Comment: Yes, I have. but it comes later in the web.xml file. after the filter mapping declaration. is that a problem?